# Postman random start and end dates

Tags: postman

How can I generate dynamic random start and end dates for a post request in the YYYY/MM/DD format? This is what I tried in the pre-request script but it does not work

```
    const moment = require('moment');
    pm.globals.set("start", moment().format(("YYYY/MM/DD")));
```

Comment: is there any requirement for start date/end date?

Comment: they have to be within a year of each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with a mix of Postman [Dynamic Variables](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/) and `momemt` for formatting. These variables get generated at execution time (when you send a request) so you have different values for each request. You can use the [following variables](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/#dates):

- `$randomDateFuture`
- `$randomDatePast`
- `$randomDateRecent`

You can use them directly as you would use a collection or global variable in query params, etc. If you want to use these variables on scripts then you have to use it like this:

```
const startDate = pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomDatePast}}')
```

So for your example in concrete [I've written a request you can see here](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/vitor-s-sandbox/request/19391207-ee91129c-be11-40ae-a7e0-692fd8df2aa5) (check pre-request script). Also posting the code here for future perservation:

```js
const moment = require('moment')

// Generate a past and future date using dynamic postman variables 
let futureDate = pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomDateFuture}}'),
    pastDate = pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomDatePast}}')

// Use moment to output the right format
futureDate = moment(futureDate).format(("YYYY/MM/DD"))
pastDate = moment(pastDate).format(("YYYY/MM/DD"))

console.log(futureDate)
console.log(pastDate)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you! this ended up working after I added

pm.variables.set("pastDate", pastDate);
pm.variables.set("futureDate", futureDate);